# Minimum comparisons needed to search an element in sorted array with more than half occurrences

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, time-complexity

Recently, I was given a question to find Minimum comparisons needed to search an element from `n` given elements, provided they are `sorted`, and with more than half(`n/2`) occurrences.

For eg. given sorted array as: `1,1,2,2,2,2,2,7,11`. Size of this array is: `9`. We need to find the minimum comparisons required to find `2`(since it has more than n/2 occurrences(`5`).

What would be the best algorithm to do so and what would be the worst case Complexity?

Options provided were:

i)   O(1)

ii)  O(n)

iii) O(log(n))

iv)  O(nlog(n))

Comment: Well binary search worst case would be `O(log(n))` which is generally what is done in this case

Comment: @crush I think the situation makes it a lot easier to test for it...

Comment: I guess it wasn't clear to me that `what would be the worst case Complexity` was referring only to finding the 2, and not any number in the array. If it's only for the 2, then it is `O(1)`.

Comment: @crush, I just gave an example to illustrate, it meant for a General case

Comment: @VarunMalhotra By `2` I meant whatever number is repeated more than n/2 occurrences if applied to a General case. It's `O(1)` for that scenario. For any other number in the array it is basically `O(log(n))`

Comment: @Varun Malhotra What's happened? You rewrote a pair of words, and my answer now is not an answer? ;-)

Comment: @MBo just an accident :p

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> provided they are sorted

In this case you have to check only one middle element, if fact that

> with more than half(n/2) occurrences

is guaranteed

Comment: how ? what if we have 2,2,2,1,4,5,2,2,1

Comment: @VarunMalhotra That wouldn't be a sorted array...that's why `MBo` highlighted that section of the question. Without a sorted array, you can't use the binary search algorithm anyways.

Comment: Oops, i forgot about that. So it means we just need to compare the number to be searched with the middle element of that array?

Comment: @VarunMalhotra Do you understand the binary search algorithm - how it operates?

Comment: @crush Yeah I know. It's a very basic one to get started with `Searching` algorithms.

Comment: @VarunMalhotra Binary search algorithm starts searching at the `n/2` position of the array. Therefore, if the search term occurs more than `n/2` times in the array, then it is guaranteed mathematically to be the first term that the search checks. That is why it is `O(1)` when searching for `2` in your example. It would be `O(log(n))` if searching for `1`, `7`, or `11`.

Comment: @crush, Yes, exactly. Nice one :)

Answer (score 2):

There can be two possible interpretations of the question. I'll explain both.

Firstly, if the question assumes that there is definitely a number which occurs `n/2` or more times, then MBo's answer suffices.

However, if there is a chance that there is no element with `n/2` occurrences, then the complexity is `O(log(n))`. We cannot merely check for the `n/2th` element. For example, in array `2, 4, 6, 6, 6, 8, 10`, the middle element is `6`, but it does not occur `n/2` or more times. The algorithm for this case goes as follows:

- Select the middle element (say `x`).
- Find the index of x in the left sub-array using binary search (say `lIndex`).
- Find the index of x in the right sub-array using binary search (say `rIndex`).
- If `rIndex - lIndex >= n/2`, then the number occurs `n/2` or more times. Otherwise, no such number is present.

Since we use binary search to find the number in left and right sub-arrays, the complexity of the above algorithm is `O(log(n))`.